# Using C types in Python

Tags: python, c, dll, ctypes

I need the following C function in Python:

```
int func(Uint8 *bytRecvBuffer, int *iRecvLen);
```

I tried in Python:

```
mydll = cdll.LoadLibrary("my.dll")

recvBuffer = None
recvLength = None

funcFunction = getattr(mydll, "func")
funcFunction(POINTER(c_ubyte(recvBuffer)), POINTER(c_int(recvLength)))
```

Error message:

> TypeError: an integer is required

What is wrong here with the parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to allocate an actual buffer and integer:

```
from ctypes import *
mydll = CDLL("my")
recvBuffer = create_string_buffer(1000)
recvLength = c_int(1000)
mydll.func(recvBuffer,byref(recvLength))
```

You can also declare the specific parameters supported by func, but then you must also be more explicit about the parameters passed:

```
mydll.func.argtypes = [POINTER(c_ubyte),POINTER(c_int)]
mydll.func.restype = c_int
recvBuffer = (c_ubyte*1000)()
recvLength = c_int(1000)
mydll.func(recvBuffer,byref(recvLength))
```

Answer (score 2):

None is not integer.

c_int(None) causes TypeError

Init your variables with 0, not None

Answer (score 0):

Did you try loading the dll with windll instead of cdll? also....isn't it pointer instead of POINTER ?

Comment: @leon22, clarification.  `POINTER(type)` takes a type and creates a pointer type for that type. `pointer(instance)` takes an instance and instantiates a pointer to that instance.

Answer (score 0):

Guessing from your initialization of `recvBuffer` and `recvLength` you want to create null pointer.

In that case you should create an instance without argument of specific type, do the following:

```
recvBuffer = POINTER(c_ubyte)()   
recvLength = POINTER(c_int)()

funcFunction(recvBuffer, recvLength)
```

if you got the buffer within python, you need to cast your fixed size array to the correct pointer type.